# I am trying to make a dictionary and I can't seem to search to see if the word already exists

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, fstream

The assignment is to write words and a definition to a file and ask the user to search through the file so it can output on the screen if the word already exists. I managed to get the first part done but I can't seem to output the definition of an already existing word. Any suggestions?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void searchFile(string word){
     ifstream ifile;
     ofstream ofile;
     ofile.open("dictionary.txt", ios::app);
     string line;

while(ofile.is_open()){
                         ifile >> line;
                         if(word == line){
                         getline(cin, line);
                         cout << line << endl;
                         ofile.close();
                         }

                         else{
                         cout << "This definition does not exist." << endl;
                         ofile.close();
                         }
                         }
}

int main(){
     char ans;
     ifstream inputFile;
     ofstream outputFile;
     string search;


outputFile.open("dictionary.txt", ios::app);

while(outputFile.is_open()){
     string word;
     string def;

     cout << "Please enter the word and press enter." << endl;
     cin >> word;
     cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
     outputFile << word;
     outputFile << " : ";

     cout << "Please enter the definition of this word." << endl;
     getline(cin, def);
     outputFile << def << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to close the dictionary? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y'){
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
    cout << "Would you like to search the dictionary? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> ans;
    if(ans == 'y'){
        cout << "What word would you like to search for?" << endl;
        cin >> search;
        searchFile(search);
    }


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `getline` and `>>` which usually doesn't end well.  Is there a reason you get a line from the file and then immediately overwrite that result?

Comment: That's actually an error I encountered, the line being overwritten. I fixed the code a bit but I still can't figure it out. Is it possible to go line by line to compare the first string and if they're equal, print out the whole line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but I made it a little easier to read.  In the searchFile function, line is not being used, did you mean to use it for something?  If you're reading an entire line in with getline, then the word you are searching for will never be equivalent to the string returned from getline, maybe try delimiting with a colon?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void searchFile(string word)
{
     ifstream ifile;
     ofstream ofile;
     ofile.open("dictionary.txt", ios::app);
     string line;
     string search;

    while(ofile.is_open())
    {
        getline(ifile, search);
        ifile >> search;
        if(word == search)
        {
            getline(ifile, search);
            cout << search << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "This definition does not exist." << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char ans;
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    string search;


    outputFile.open("dictionary.txt", ios::app);

    while(outputFile.is_open())
    {
        string word;
        string def;

        cout << "Please enter the word and press enter." << endl;
        cin >> word;
        cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
        outputFile << word;
        outputFile << ": ";

        cout << "Please enter the definition of this word." << endl;
        getline(cin, def);
        outputFile << def << endl;

        cout << "Would you like to close the dictionary? y/n" << endl;
        cin >> ans;
        if(ans == 'y')
        {
            outputFile.close();
        }
    }

    cout << "Would you like to search the dictionary? y/n" << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    if(ans == 'y')
    {
        cout << "What word would you like to search for?" << endl;
        cin >> search;
        searchFile(search);
    }

    system("pause")
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is search the file for the word (which is the first string in each line) and when it finds that line, it'd output the entire line, which contains the definition

Comment: `void search(string searchWord)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string str;
    inFile.open("dictionary.txt");
    
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline(inFile, str);
        if(str.find(':') != string::npos)
            if(str.find(searchWord) != string::npos)
                cout << str << endl;
        
    }
}
`

Comment: @JMercer, I know you're not allowed to post comments (something I don't agree with), but please don't substitute with answers meant to be comments.

Comment: No problem, the code I posted above does what was asked though.

Comment: Oh my that actually works. Can you explain to me why? If you don't mind

Comment: It's pretty simple: the search function is passed a search string; dictionary.txt is opened; getline; check if it contains a ':' (you could leave this out); check if it contains the search string; if it does, print the line; repeat until end of file.